# MUI Datepicker - is it possible to only set date once a both month and year selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```js
<div className="datePicker">
  <DatePicker
    inputFormat="yyyy-MM"
    views={["year", "month"]}
    label="Month and Year"
    minDate={dayjs(earliestDate)}
    value={selectedDate}
    onChange={(date) => {
      setSelectedMonth(null);
      setSelectedYear(null);
      if (date && date.year && date.month) {
        // Both year and month are selected, now you can call handleDateChange
        handleDateChange(date);
      }
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />
    )}
  />
</div>
```

I have a MUI DatePicker which I have setup to display only the year and the month.  To put this in context it will call an API based off the year and month chosen. When I load the application, I can see the datepicker dropdown.  I can see as soon as I pick a year, I can see my API is called with whatever month was previously used (even though I am initialising the state variable with useState(null).

Is there any way to hold off the on change event until both the year and month have been selected? I have tried the above but that doesn't seem to work.  Likewise, I tried to handle this in the handleDateChange method by using:

```js
setSelectedYear(null);
setSelectedMonth(null);
```

and only calling my api once both values were poplulated, but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should use a different button to call your API. Instead of calling it in the onchanged.